# Error with overriding KafkaAutoConfiguration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I'm trying to override the KafkaAutoConfiguration because I have separated producer and consumer configurations into different property files.

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods=false)
@ConditionalOnClass(value=org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.class)
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:producer-config2.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:consumer-config.properties")
})
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value=KafkaProperties.class)
@Import(value={org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.class,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaStreamsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.class})
public class KafkaAutoConfiguration {

}
```

The issue is coming from line 8 `@Import(value={org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.class,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaStreamsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.class})` 
 where I'm getting the errors: 
`The type org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration is not visible`, 
`The type org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaStreamsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration is not visible`
But when I F3 into this class in my IDE, I'm able to see both of the classes just fine. What's the issue with this? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
class KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration {
```

The class is package-private and thus only visible to other classes in the same package; you can't reference it from your class.

The fact that you can navigate to it in your IDE is irrelevant.

Comment: Is there a solution I can implement as a workaround then? It seems to be working when I remove that line entirely, but I'm scared that it's going to break something down the line

Comment: Have you tried `public class MyKafkaConfig extends KafkaAutoConfiguration`? (and override its `@Bean` methods - the ones you want to configure differently)

Comment: Oh! That works I think. I just included the extra `@PropertySources` and then passed in the `KafkaProperties` as the constructor parameter. Thank you very much